# How to concat one column records in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have 2 columns and want to concatenate both, below is the small set of data:

```
ID         Comments

32412     CLOSE AS NORMAL
32412     UNDER REVIEW
```

I want this to be come as below ,so basically view is that grouping by ID and concatenate the comments.

```
ID      Comments

32412  CLOSE AS NORMAL
       UNDER REVIEW
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking about actually. And Have you tried something ? (I didn't downvote you but I'm voting to close this question for being unclear)

Answer (score 2):

An alternate way to do this without using SQL query:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

val myUDF = udf[String, mutable.WrappedArray[String]](_.mkString(" "))
df.groupBy($"id")
  .agg(collect_list("comments").as("comments"))
  .withColumn("comments", myUDF($"comments"))
  .show()
```

It requires `HiveContext` as `SQLContext` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a UDF (user defined function) for this. Assuming you have a `DataFrame` named `df` with the data, you can try something like this:

```
import scala.collection.mutable
sqlContext.udf.register("ArrayToString",(a: mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => a.mkString("\n"))
df.registerTempTable("IDsAndComments")
val new_df = sqlContext.sql("WITH Data AS (SELECT ID, collect_list(Comments) AS cmnts FROM IDsAndComments GROUP BY ID) SELECT ID, ArrayToString(cmnts) AS Comments FROM Data")
```

What happens here is that you define a new function for the `sqlContext` to use when it parses the SQL code. This function takes an `WrappedArray` (which is the type of array you get from Spark's DataFrames), and turn it to a string, where every element of the array is separated by a new line.

The `collect_list` is function that returns an array of the values it grouped. Note that it's a `HiveContext` function, so you need your `sqlContext` to be a `HiveContext`